# Weblogic 12.2.1.2 server definition issue in Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, java-8, weblogic12c

I have installed Weblogic 12.2.1.2 with JDK 1.8.0_161 and now i am adding server in Eclipse Neon 4.6.3. When i specify wlserver in Weblogic Runtime nothing happens, even if i manually add JDK.

[Weblogic Runtime Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0cBe.jpg)

What could be the problem?

Note: In Eclipse Kepler definition of weblogic server (12.1.2.0) works fine without an issue.

Comment: I suggest you to write a web application with one jsp page and test it. If it does not run watch a youtube video how to add weblogic in eclipse.

Comment: I know how to add weblogic server in eclipse. Done it many times in Eclipse Kepler with earlier versions of weblogic. Environment variables are also set correctly.